# Return Resolved Observable from Inside of a Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, ionic2

I'm trying to build a custom Angular 2 http request by extending the default and I'm using Ionic 2 local storage to store the auth token. (Will likely use file system in future). My issue is how to return a resolved promise from my http service so I can subscribe to the Observable within my component. I've tried Observable.fromPromise and other variations to no avail.

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

  // Get the token used for this request.
  // * Need to return this promise resolved.
  var promise = this.storage.get('token').then(token => {

    if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
    } else {
    // we have to add the token to the url object
      url.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
    }

    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

}
```

Idea is based on this blog post, but Ionic storage returns a promise. http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Comment: Who is the `user`?

Comment: Should have been token.

Comment: It isn't convenient to deal with observable inside `then`. I guess it should be something like `return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token')).map(token => { ...; return url }).mergeMap(url => super.request(...))`

Comment: What happens when you use `fromPromise` ?

Comment: May be doing something wrong but usually something about requiring an Observable to be returned.

Comment: @Meir converts a `Promise` into an `Observable`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if that storage returns a promise which is compatible with Rx, but if it is then the solution should look like this:

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    return Observable
        .fromPromise(this.storage.get('token'))
        .flatMap(token => {

            if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
                if (!options) {
                    // let's make option object
                    options = {headers: new Headers()};
                }
                options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
            } else {
                // we have to add the token to the url object
                url.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
            }

            return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));

        });
    });

}
```

If promise is not compatible with observables there's still a way to do that, though it's not that elegant:

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    return Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {

        this.storage.get('token').then(token => {

            if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
                if (!options) {
                    // let's make option object
                    options = {headers: new Headers()};
                }
                options.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
            } else {
                // we have to add the token to the url object
                url.headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
            }

            super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this)).subscribe(result => {
                observer.next(result);
                observer.complete();
            });

        }).catch(error => {
            observer.error(error);
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: First option worked, thanks!. I wasn't using flatmap earlier. Also needed to add import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergemap'; to get flatmap to work.