# Angular 2 ionic 2 - Creating common service loads constructor for each service intialzation

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Sample hierarchy of my ionic 2 app..

few services which implements my baseService class to inject header and all that in each http requests.

Now I have a NativeStorage.get of user's info in constructor of the baseService in which I get user data already and update my local variable in that class only to be sent in HTTP requests.

But problem is each time I hit a new service it reinitialize my baseService again and so my user data gets empty and by the time NativeStorage.get starts its work http req is already gone with empty requests

base service

```
export class CommonRestProvider {}
```

a sample service

```
export class PlaceListService extends CommonRestProvider{ }
```

base service dependecies setting in app.module.ts

```
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, ConstantsService, CommonRestProvider]
```

Comment: Needed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899313/return-resolved-observable-from-inside-of-a-promise

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set header for every http request, you can check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request/43224334#43224334).

And, if you still want to use your current solution, you can use`Observable` or `Promise` for your user data, and for every requests, you need to use `subscribe` or `then` to send request in them.